# Postgres Create function to copy data from one month to all months until end of quarter

Tags: sql, postgresql, reporting

I have data points defined for 1 month in a quarter and need that to be replicated for all months in that quarter and so on for all months. For eg the data I have is:

```
month_start  C1   C2
2017-01-01   10   21
2017-01-01   17   42
2017-01-01   22    7
2017-04-01   13    6
2017-04-01    8   99
```

Now I want to change it so that the data is duplicated within the quarter based on the month_start as follows:

```
month_start   C1      C2  
2017-01-01    10      21  
2017-01-01    17      42  
2017-01-01    22      7  
2017-02-01    10      21  
2017-02-01    17      42  
2017-02-01    22      7  
2017-03-01    10      21  
2017-03-01    17      42  
2017-03-01    22      7  
2017-04-01    13      6  
2017-04-01     8      99  
2017-05-01    13      6  
2017-05-01     8      99  
2017-06-01    13      6  
2017-06-01     8      99
```

I need to do this for reporting purposes as the report is a monthly report. Any idea on how I can achieve this. Let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: SO isn't a free coding service. What have you tried (add it to question) and ask for specific assistance if that isnt working.  Postgres is good at creating series by the way, research postgres series perhaps.

Comment: By the way, I hope there are more columns available to help explain why sometimes there are 3 rows per date and 2 rows at other dates

Answer (score 0):

You can duplicate rows for two additional months using the function [`generate_series()`:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html)

```
with my_table(month_start, C1, C2) as (
values
    ('2017-01-01'::date, 10, 21),
    ('2017-01-01', 17, 42),
    ('2017-01-01', 22, 7),
    ('2017-04-01', 13, 6),
    ('2017-04-01', 8, 99)
)

select ms::date as month_start, c1, c2
from my_table
cross join generate_series(month_start, month_start+ interval '2 months', '1 month') ms
order by month_start, row_number() over (order by month_start);

 month_start | c1 | c2 
-------------+----+----
 2017-01-01  | 10 | 21
 2017-01-01  | 17 | 42
 2017-01-01  | 22 |  7
 2017-02-01  | 10 | 21
 2017-02-01  | 17 | 42
 2017-02-01  | 22 |  7
 2017-03-01  | 10 | 21
 2017-03-01  | 17 | 42
 2017-03-01  | 22 |  7
 2017-04-01  | 13 |  6
 2017-04-01  |  8 | 99
 2017-05-01  | 13 |  6
 2017-05-01  |  8 | 99
 2017-06-01  | 13 |  6
 2017-06-01  |  8 | 99
(15 rows)
```

Note that `row_number()` is used only to preserve the original sort order of rows.